# Would angular js replace Jsp?

Tags: jsp, backbone.js, single-page-application

I'm new to Angular JS and SPA (Single page application). Are these technologies extension to JavaScript? They dynamically generate a DOM and need no refresh or submit etc. Would these JS technologies replace the traditional way of writing code in JSPs.

Comment: angular only runs on the browser, it doesn't have any of the capabilities that only servers have (connecting to a database for example)

Comment: when working with angular, you usually have two parts to your application: The server-side code usually in the form of an API, and the client side code that uses that api to get information to display to the client. Both sides can be written in javascript, but the capabilities on the client aren't always the same as the capabilities available on the server, even if both are javascript. It can be hard to understand for someone not familiar with javascript and client/server communication.

Comment: Researching "Mean Stack" would likely be a good place to begin, if you want to use javascript both client-side and server-side. Keep in mind though that the parts are interchangeable. you can swap mongodb for mssql or any other dbms, node.js for jsp/asp/whatever server-side language, etc to make the application fit your needs/resources. the "Mean Stack" is just a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main conceptual difference between JSP's and an SPA framework like Angular is whether the page is being dynamically generated in the browser (client-side) or on the server. The idea of an SPA is that you don't often (or ever) have to retrieve the entire page from the server once it's loaded once. You merely update parts of the page that have changed on the client (though this is often in response to data retrieved from the server).

Angular is a JavaScript framework, so yes, it is an extension to the JavaScript language. It's probably a more mature way of doing the type of dynamic page interactions you're used to with JavaScript.

Whether or not Angular should "replace" JSP's is a very opinionated question, and you can actually use the two side-by-side (though they compete a bit).

Answer (score 1):

Jsp is used and evaluated while on the server and it does have its own limitations for constructing the html page. You cannot do so many complex things with Jsp yet it is secure because it happens on the server. Jsp doesn't care about the browser used to display the page so it can run pretty much on any browser.

Angular on the other hand is more advanced in terms of constructing web pages and making the user experience smooth to the user. It runs totally on the client side (browser) so it won't be supported by feature phone or old browsers.